# can Intel Atom N450 1.66 GHz run ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, laptop, custom-distributions

Can my old laptop with a Intel Atom N450 1.66 GHz run ubuntu without that much lag? It only has 1gb of ram which i feel might be an issue

Comment: The answer is negative.

Comment: what if i add more ram

Comment: Lubuntu will probably work OK.

Comment: From first hand experience, Ubuntu does run on Atom N450, but not very well. More RAM would help, but it won't change the fact that the hardware it old and weak.

Comment: Even plain Ubuntu 16.04 works fine in that hardware, depending of how many tab you have open in a browser, any browser. 1GB RAM is quite limited. Use something lighter like Xubuntu or Lubuntu and you end up with a quite usable computer (for light tasks).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score -1):

The real issue will be whether or not you are able to install AT ALL. If your laptop does not read DVDs and cannot boot from a flashdrive (which I suspect), then you’re stuck. If you can boot from a live DVD or flashdrive, then you’re in luck. The Ubuntu installer will allow you to try it out without installing. Run this option and goof around with it for a while. If it lags too much then you are best going with a lighter weight Linux version.

Comment: I am installing elementary OS at the moment, its going a lil slow but its installing without issues so far.
I chose it over any other dist because it seemed to run alright on my vm with very limited resources, I will try Lubuntu later

Comment: All Atom based "netbook" and similar of that era and before can boot from USB flashdrives and even Ubuntu 16.04 works acceptably. For a little fast results use something lighter like Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Comment: @bashBedlam it's a good idea to Google the computer in question before speculating it can't boot from USB.